# Remove duplicated fasta sequence (bash of biopython method)

Tags: bash, biopython, fasta

I have a fasta file such as:

```
>sequence1_CP [seq  virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

>sequence2 [virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

>sequence3
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

>sequence4_CP hypothetical protein [another virus]
MLRHSCVMPQQKLKKRFFFLRRLRKILRYFFTCNFLNLFFINREYNIENITLSYLKKERIPVWKTSDMSN
IVRKWWMFHRKTQLEDNIEIKKDIQLYHFFYNGLFIKTNYPYVYHIDKKKKYDFNDMKVIYLPAIHMHSK

>sequence5 hypothetical protein [another virus]
MLRHSCVMPQQKLKKRFFFLRRLRKILRYFFTCNFLNLFFINREYNIENITLSYLKKERIPVWKTSDMSN
IVRKWWMFHRKTQLEDNIEIKKDIQLYHFFYNGLFIKTNYPYVYHIDKKKKYDFNDMKVIYLPAIHMHSK

>sequence6 |hypothetical protein[virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNLD
ITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

>sequence7 |hypothetical protein[virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNLD
ITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE
```

And in this file I would like to remove duplicated sequence and get:

```
>sequence1_CP [seq  virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

>sequence4_CP hypothetical protein [another virus]
MLRHSCVMPQQKLKKRFFFLRRLRKILRYFFTCNFLNLFFINREYNIENITLSYLKKERIPVWKTSDMSN
IVRKWWMFHRKTQLEDNIEIKKDIQLYHFFYNGLFIKTNYPYVYHIDKKKKYDFNDMKVIYLPAIHMHSK

>sequence6 |hypothetical protein[virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNLD
ITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE
```

Here as you can see the content after the `> name` for `sequence1_CP`, `sequence2` and `sequence3` is the same, then I want only to keep on of the 3. But if one of the 3 sequences have a `_CP` in its name, then I want to keep this one especially. If there is none `_CP` in any of them it does not mater which one I keep.

- So for the first duplicates between `Sequence1_CP`, `Sequence2` and `Sequence3` I keep `sequence1_CP`
- For the second duplicates between `sequence4_CP` and `sequence5`  I keep `sequence4_CP`
- And for the third duplicates between sequence6 and `sequence7` I keep the first one `sequence6`

Does someone have an idea using biopython or a bash method?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this awk one-liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS=""}{if(!seen[$2,$3]++)print}' file
```

Output:

```
>sequence1_CP [seq  virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE
>sequence4_CP hypothetical protein [another virus]
MLRHSCVMPQQKLKKRFFFLRRLRKILRYFFTCNFLNLFFINREYNIENITLSYLKKERIPVWKTSDMSN
IVRKWWMFHRKTQLEDNIEIKKDIQLYHFFYNGLFIKTNYPYVYHIDKKKKYDFNDMKVIYLPAIHMHSK
>sequence6 |hypothetical protein[virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNLD
ITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE
```

Above relies on observation that the sequences are in order where the `_CP`s come before others like in the sample. If this is not in fact the case, use the following. It stores the first instance of each sequence which is overwritten if a `_CP` sequence is found:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS=""}{if(!($2,$3) in seen||$1~/^[^ ]+_CP /)seen[$2,$3]=$0}END{for(i in seen)print (++j>1?ORS:"") seen[i]}' file
```

Or in pretty-print:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="\n"
    RS=""
}
{
    if(!($2,$3) in seen||$1~/^[^ ]+_CP /)
        seen[$2,$3]=$0
}
END {
    for(i in seen)
        print (++j>1?ORS:"") seen[i]
}' file
```

The output order is awk default ie. appears random.

**Update** If @kvantour's BOTH comments are valid in this case, use this awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="\n"
    RS=""
}
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
        k=(i==2?"":k) $i
    if(!(k in seen)||$1~/^[^ ]+_CP /)
        seen[k]=$0
}
END {
    for(i in seen)
        print (++j>1?ORS:"") seen[i]
}' file
```

Output now:

```
>sequence1_CP [seq  virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

>sequence4_CP hypothetical protein [another virus]
MLRHSCVMPQQKLKKRFFFLRRLRKILRYFFTCNFLNLFFINREYNIENITLSYLKKERIPVWKTSDMSN
IVRKWWMFHRKTQLEDNIEIKKDIQLYHFFYNGLFIKTNYPYVYHIDKKKKYDFNDMKVIYLPAIHMHSK
```

Comment: I believe solution need additional logic to handle _CP names

Comment: This is not necessary a duplicate sequence. You should remove the newlines.

Comment: @kvantour Oh is that the case? There is actually such a case in the sample. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @JamesBrown Also, you should know that multi-line sequences can have any number of lines ;-)

Comment: @kvantour Aww c..p. I need to throw in a `for` loop. In a sec.

Comment: Hello, I actually works but the processing time is too long...

Comment: @chippycentra How long is _too long_ and does the data exist online?

Comment: I can try to upload it and share it to you but the number of sequence is 2196136 and the size is 657M

Answer (score 2):

In a fasta file, identical sequences are not necessarily split at the same position. So it is paramount to merge the sequences before comparing. Furthermore, sequences can have upper case or lower case, but are in the end case insensitive:

The following awk will do exactly that:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n"; FS="\n"}
       {seq="";for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) seq=seq toupper($i)}
       !(seq in a){print; a[seq]}' file.fasta
```

There exists actually a version of awk which has been upgraded to process fasta files:

```
$ bioawk -c fastx '!(seq in a){print; a[seq]}' file.fasta
```

---

**Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
(Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
. I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).

Answer (score 1):

Or pure-bash solution (following same log as separate `perl` solution):

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -A p
    # Read inbound data into associative array 'p'
while read id ; do
        read s1 ; read s2 ; read s3
        key="$s1:$s2"
        prev=${p[$key]}
        if [[ -z "$prev" || "$id" = %+CP% ]] ; then p[$key]=$id  ; fi
done
    # Print all data
for k in "${!p[@]}" ; do
        echo -e "${p[$k]}\n${k/:/\\n}\n"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python program that will provide you with results you are looking for:

```
import fileinput
import re

seq=""
nameseq={}
seqnames={}
for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.rstrip() 
    if re.search( "^>", line ):
      if seq:
        nameseq[ id ] = seq
        if seq in seqnames:
          if re.search( "_CP", id ):
            seqnames[ seq ] = id
        else:
          seqnames[ seq ] = id
      seq = ""
      id = line
      continue
    seq += line

for k,v in seqnames.iteritems():
  print(v)
  print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with `perl`. Assuming code in m.pl ,can be wrapped into bash script

Hopefully, code will help find medicines, and not develop new viruses :-)

perl m.pl < input-file

```
! /usr/bin/perl
use strict ;

my %to_id ;
local $/ = "\n\n";
while ( <> ) {
  chomp ;
  my ($id, $s1, $s2 ) = split("\n") ;
  my $key = "$s1\n$s2" ;
  my $prev_id = $to_id{$key} ;
  $to_id{$key} = $id if !defined($prev_id) || $id =~ /_CP/ ;
} ;
print "$to_id{$_}\n$_\n\n" foreach(keys(%to_id)) ;
```

It's not clear what is the expected order. Perl code will print directly from hash. Can be customized, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Biopython answer. Be aware that you only have two unique sequences in your example (sequence 6 and 7 only show a character more in the first line but are essentially the same protein sequence as 1).

```py
from Bio import SeqIO

seen = []
records = []
# examples are in sequences.fasta
for record in SeqIO.parse("sequences.fasta", "fasta"):
    if str(record.seq) not in seen:
        seen.append(str(record.seq))
        records.append(record)

# printing to console
for record in records:
    print(record.name)
    print(record.seq)

# writing to a fasta file
SeqIO.write(records, "unique_sequences.fasta", "fasta")
```

For more info you can try the [biopython cookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html)