# Remove duplicated sequence into fasta file (huge file)

Tags: bash, awk, fasta

Hello I have a huge fasta file such as :

```
  >sequence1_CP [seq  virus]
    MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
    DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

    >sequence2 [virus]
    MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
    DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

    >sequence3
    MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
    DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

    >sequence4_CP hypothetical protein [another virus]
    MLRHSCVMPQQKLKKRFFFLRRLRKILRYFFTCNFLNLFFINREYNIENITLSYLKKERIPVWKTSDMSN
    IVRKWWMFHRKTQLEDNIEIKKDIQLYHFFYNGLFIKTNYPYVYHIDKKKKYDFNDMKVIYLPAIHMHSK

    >sequence5 hypothetical protein [another virus]
    MLRHSCVMPQQKLKKRFFFLRRLRKILRYFFTCNFLNLFFINREYNIENITLSYLKKERIPVWKTSDMSN
    IVRKWWMFHRKTQLEDNIEIKKDIQLYHFFYNGLFIKTNYPYVYHIDKKKKYDFNDMKVIYLPAIHMHSK

    >sequence6 |hypothetical protein[virus]
    MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNLD
    ITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

    >sequence7 |hypothetical protein[virus]
    MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNLD
    ITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

>sequence8 |hypothetical protein[Musca domestica salivary gland hypertrophy virus]
MNKITRTDYLLNKLCRPQDGDDNLVASFMPCERAAIRRKYTTLYAYNYTECPHRILETCK
LQRIPYFTCIEYRANVECVERHVCDIFPVHIGLRLDRQIYAFLYGDDELNSPAVQRTMYD
LYGTIFVVSPQYFSNIFTNRKEIIHSSRDSDKLYNIYMYDVHDRGHRIWMTADANKTCIF
RNSNGQEHVIEASQSFRDFIDGIEYEVDIQRHMNFERMFEAFARYQPINDIDDLSNKNIL

>sequence9 |hypothetical protein[Musca domestica salivary gland hypertrophy virus]
MNKITRTDYLLNKLCRPQDGDDNLVASFMPCERAAIRRKYTTLYAYNYTECPHRILETCK
LQRIPYFTCIEYRANVECVERHVCDIFPVHIGLRLDRQIYAFLYGDDELNSPAVQRTMYD
LYGTIFVVSPQYFSNIFTNRKEIIHSSRDSDKLYNIYMYDVHDRGHRIWMTADANKTCIF
RNSNGQEHVIEASQSFRDFIDGIEYEVDIQRHMNFERMFEAFARYQPINDIDDLSNKNIL
```

and I am looking for a method in order to remove duplicated sequences :

here for instance sequence1_CP, sequence2, sequence3, sequence6 and sequence7 have exactly the same sequence, then I want only to keep one. Same for sequence4_CP and sequence5 or sequence6 and sequence7 or sequence 8 and 9.

The number of sequence in the file is : `2196136`
So I would need a fast method...

Here I should get in the exemple:

```
>sequence1_CP [seq  virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

>sequence4_CP hypothetical protein [another virus]
MLRHSCVMPQQKLKKRFFFLRRLRKILRYFFTCNFLNLFFINREYNIENITLSYLKKERIPVWKTSDMSN
IVRKWWMFHRKTQLEDNIEIKKDIQLYHFFYNGLFIKTNYPYVYHIDKKKKYDFNDMKVIYLPAIHMHSK

>sequence8 |hypothetical protein[Musca domestica salivary gland hypertrophy virus]
MNKITRTDYLLNKLCRPQDGDDNLVASFMPCERAAIRRKYTTLYAYNYTECPHRILETCK
LQRIPYFTCIEYRANVECVERHVCDIFPVHIGLRLDRQIYAFLYGDDELNSPAVQRTMYD
LYGTIFVVSPQYFSNIFTNRKEIIHSSRDSDKLYNIYMYDVHDRGHRIWMTADANKTCIF
RNSNGQEHVIEASQSFRDFIDGIEYEVDIQRHMNFERMFEAFARYQPINDIDDLSNKNIL
```

Ps: I have to take into account that the lines matters, for instance sequence1_CP is identical to sequence 6 and 7

Comment: The previous ones did not please you in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58862586/remove-duplicated-fasta-sequence-bash-of-biopython-method ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '{rec=$0; $1=""; gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"")} !seen[$0]++{print rec}' file
>sequence1_CP [seq  virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

>sequence4_CP hypothetical protein [another virus]
MLRHSCVMPQQKLKKRFFFLRRLRKILRYFFTCNFLNLFFINREYNIENITLSYLKKERIPVWKTSDMSN
IVRKWWMFHRKTQLEDNIEIKKDIQLYHFFYNGLFIKTNYPYVYHIDKKKKYDFNDMKVIYLPAIHMHSK

>sequence8 |hypothetical protein[Musca domestica salivary gland hypertrophy virus]
MNKITRTDYLLNKLCRPQDGDDNLVASFMPCERAAIRRKYTTLYAYNYTECPHRILETCK
LQRIPYFTCIEYRANVECVERHVCDIFPVHIGLRLDRQIYAFLYGDDELNSPAVQRTMYD
LYGTIFVVSPQYFSNIFTNRKEIIHSSRDSDKLYNIYMYDVHDRGHRIWMTADANKTCIF
RNSNGQEHVIEASQSFRDFIDGIEYEVDIQRHMNFERMFEAFARYQPINDIDDLSNKNIL
```

Comment: hello, no If you put the sequence into one line seq1, seq2 3  seq6 and 7 are the same...

Comment: You never said that that was required or that newlines didn't matter.

Comment: yes sorry I forgot :/

Comment: I updated my answer to accommodate that but please edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="\n"
    RS=""
}
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
        k=(i==2?"":k) $i

    if(!(k in seen)||$1~/^[^ ]+_CP /)
        seen[k]=$0
}
END {
    for(i in seen)
        print (++j>1?ORS:"") seen[i]
}' file
```

Output:

```
>sequence8 |hypothetical protein[Musca domestica salivary gland hypertrophy virus]
MNKITRTDYLLNKLCRPQDGDDNLVASFMPCERAAIRRKYTTLYAYNYTECPHRILETCK
LQRIPYFTCIEYRANVECVERHVCDIFPVHIGLRLDRQIYAFLYGDDELNSPAVQRTMYD
LYGTIFVVSPQYFSNIFTNRKEIIHSSRDSDKLYNIYMYDVHDRGHRIWMTADANKTCIF
RNSNGQEHVIEASQSFRDFIDGIEYEVDIQRHMNFERMFEAFARYQPINDIDDLSNKNIL

>sequence1_CP [seq  virus]
MQCKSGTNNVFTAIKYTTNNNIIYKSENNDNIIFTKNIFNVVTTKDAFIFSKNRGIMNL
DITKKFDYHEHRPKLCVFKIINTQYVNSPEKMIDAWPTMDIVALITE

>sequence4_CP hypothetical protein [another virus]
MLRHSCVMPQQKLKKRFFFLRRLRKILRYFFTCNFLNLFFINREYNIENITLSYLKKERIPVWKTSDMSN
IVRKWWMFHRKTQLEDNIEIKKDIQLYHFFYNGLFIKTNYPYVYHIDKKKKYDFNDMKVIYLPAIHMHSK
```