# Remove duplicated sequences according to their ID names (bash or python)

Tags: python, bash

I'm looking for a python or bash script in order to remove duplicated sequence by `their ID`.

Here is the input file:

```
>AJZ73152.1 hypothetical protein [Venturia canescens]
MAGLSTDKTDKTTVLLQYEVSHENYLARCIPGTRLHAKIHGSLPVLASSILTHNLDVKRADVFYLSGSSD
GSYYCDLPVSPQASKRVGDQTRETLRAQC

>AJZ73158.1 hypothetical protein [Venturia canescens]
MAGLSTDKTDKTTVLLQYEVSHENYLARCIPGTRLHAKIHGSLPVLASSILTHNLDVKRADVFYLSGSSD
GSYYCDLPVSPQASKRVGDQTRETLRAQC

>AKH40348.1 putative gp75-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MDQTDLLYTPQFEDYILEFCRAVSTDTTITAISPIIEVLKQSEYLRYLMKDPSNDSAKTCVRNFIVSKSH
LPQDFLYKFLAIVTMKISLAPSNVGFIHQSYNAKVIANNLQPTSRITNLTIAARQDQLRAESKNAITYVK
QTRMPPQILRMKFNDDLLPRCINAIGDLNQVIIEGNRSNGRDVGDFVRTVLK

>AKH40367.1 putative gp75-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MDQTDLLYTPQFEDYILEFCRAVSTDTTITAISPIIEVLKQSEYLRYLMKDPSNDSAKTCVRNFIVSKSH
LPQDFLYKFLAIVTMKISLAPSNVGFIHQSYNAKVIANNLQPTSRITNLTIAARQDQLRAESKNAITYVK
QTRMPPQILRMKFNDDLLPRCINAIGDLNQVIIEGNRSNGRDVGDFVRTVLK

>AZH40350.1 putative gp75-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MDQTDLLYTPQFEDYILEFCRAVSTDTTITAISPIIEVLKQSEYLRYLMKDPSNDSAKTCVRNFIVSKSH
LPQDFLYKFLAIVTMKISLAPSNVGFIHQSYNAKVIANNLQPTSRITNLTIAARQDQLRAESKNAITYVK
QTRMPPQILRMKFNDDLLPRCINAIGDLNQVIIEGNRSNGRDVGDFVRTVLK

>AKH40359.1 putative lef-4 [Kallithea virus]
MEEDNDNIPSTSLKVLNLLNIQVDTQQQQTVISNVANEHVANEYVSSEHVAIANEHVDNVNQSTTNAEFV
QKMPQTEVSMPTPTNPIYDEWESTIAIPITEEQYNIYKQKSHKSDVIFLFKNGTRLSCRTMQKKTTTYCR
NLISFYRNHWYPIRRTTAVESIEQLPPLYACDKVIFRLVVYHQNNIRISYNMEECAQGVKYNVEYEIEYK
RGISYREILIYERRLIRTVLQDNYEIKRQILSLVDLFSYVMTKVQMWHCFDPNKDYIWAYKWNGIKAKFL
ITDKLSDNGSNLTYIWPDANNITIEECHGNNISALVNFCFLVEIMDDCIVLIEAIGASIDQDIYTTEPAT
NSYVLKYLKDQNTSLKVGNKPVIIQEYYPPPLPNSYNREKFDGMIIVQDDMIIKWKIPTIDVKCIAPFKY
KIADDVLDFDFEGIPGKIYEISYKNEILRQRNDRIVASSPQEYAIFLESAKHLQ

>AKH40361.1 putative gp93-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MDLTLEHVTSWSCHLHSKETCVMKYYNGSYYHVIPVKNISVLAQTYNSQKIPDEFWEDLGPTPYMTAIYY
SDCVANVDMFRIILELFRNLDDSFLKFSTSNTPSDFIKRHIITDGIKRITLCNKHLLKSCKTKSNRPQTF
YTKDQWIKAILKGLFPKIDSSDKSGIPTNTPDWAIKLYPRGATSISAVTTPSSQMTHLAN

>AKH40366.1 putative gp93-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MDLTLEHVTSWSCHLHSKETCVMKYYNGSYYHVIPVKNISVLAQTYNSQKIPDEFWEDLGPTPYMTAIYY
SDCVANVDMFRIILELFRNLDDSFLKFSTSNTPSDFIKRHIITDGIKRITLCNKHLLKSCKTKSNRPQTF
YTKDQWIKAILKGLFPKIDSSDKSGIPTNTPDWAIKLYPRGATSISAVTTPSSQMTHLAN

>AKH40367.1 putative gp19-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MGVIRMTWNILSILITVIFVIALIWFVLYPTPIKYVLQCFVPKTEYEPNANYTTVKNYILYTNAKSNHTK
LIVIIPGGAGLLNSIANIYGFMNKLNETLGDDYDILTFSYPVRFKHTIRDSMLRVNEVLSDFTHYEEIHG
IGLSFGSLLLGAFNNKESNILSSQQMQVPQIGIKFKTFTGICGMYQPFFNVKLLTWLFDFYIMRGTPGIK
LYSCYGMPIPKLIITSNSDFLVSQSTKFLQSENAESLSYPTANLPHTFPQYINLPEAQQSIVKIVDFIKQ
NSN

>AKH40369.1 putative gp83-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MSESKLQHLHPEIINYYKSIKANGLKSPKMENNEEFITTLDRVEDDFKIPFISTYVLINNAYRHELSSNR
AKSIKQNIHAIREAKDVKIRTEVTAKVNKFEFIPSHFYTCSSKAIKVAVALFLRPAYTETLKRDFIFSLL
NHHSKTHTVSDVIDLCQKTIGDVRAFIKTVGNLNTTEKQRKQLICGLIECSELLRDRLCSKLAISVSLNG
YISLISLYLKHGHLKNVIPFEPLINLYVKESIAKCTQEEERVKILNQFKVDPVATIDDVIKGLPPAPNKV
SNSSTKSCVFKPDQNYQYYKGAPNYTRDIITTYHIEHGRRYRIQTYNDCLYDVLGYTLEAPNFLEATHSP
TTNGISAIEHEIYDRMSWSDRLNLIRFRTKIRIEDAKGSELNDYHGNSTDITISWFDDNEISCSKTISLK
KSDNKK
```

So the basic Idea is that I want to remove a sequence if its `second name` is duplicated. 
For instance :

```
>AJZ73152.1 hypothetical protein [Venturia canescens]
MAGLSTDKTDKTTVLLQYEVSHENYLARCIPGTRLHAKIHGSLPVLASSILTHNLDVKRADVFYLSGSSD
GSYYCDLPVSPQASKRVGDQTRETLRAQC
```

- First name= `>AJZ73152.1`
- Second name= `hypothetical protein [Venturia canescens]`

So for the above example:

`>AJZ73152.1`  and `>AJZ73158.1` have both the same `second name` "hypothetical protein [Venturia canescens]"
So I keep only one of them

`>AKH40348.1`, `>AKH40367.1` and `>AZH40350.1` have all the same `second name` "gp75-like protein [Kallithea virus]"
So I keep only one of them

`>AKH40359.1`, `>AKH40367.1` and `>AKH40369.1` have all `no duplicate second name`, I keel them all.

`>AKH40366.1` and `AKH40361.1` have both the same `second name` "putative gp93-like protein [Kallithea virus]"
So I keep only one of them

Here is what I should get as output:

```
>AJZ73152.1 hypothetical protein [Venturia canescens]
MAGLSTDKTDKTTVLLQYEVSHENYLARCIPGTRLHAKIHGSLPVLASSILTHNLDVKRADVFYLSGSSD
GSYYCDLPVSPQASKRVGDQTRETLRAQC

>AKH40348.1 putative gp75-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MDQTDLLYTPQFEDYILEFCRAVSTDTTITAISPIIEVLKQSEYLRYLMKDPSNDSAKTCVRNFIVSKSH
LPQDFLYKFLAIVTMKISLAPSNVGFIHQSYNAKVIANNLQPTSRITNLTIAARQDQLRAESKNAITYVK
QTRMPPQILRMKFNDDLLPRCINAIGDLNQVIIEGNRSNGRDVGDFVRTVLK

>AKH40359.1 putative lef-4 [Kallithea virus]
MEEDNDNIPSTSLKVLNLLNIQVDTQQQQTVISNVANEHVANEYVSSEHVAIANEHVDNVNQSTTNAEFV
QKMPQTEVSMPTPTNPIYDEWESTIAIPITEEQYNIYKQKSHKSDVIFLFKNGTRLSCRTMQKKTTTYCR
NLISFYRNHWYPIRRTTAVESIEQLPPLYACDKVIFRLVVYHQNNIRISYNMEECAQGVKYNVEYEIEYK
RGISYREILIYERRLIRTVLQDNYEIKRQILSLVDLFSYVMTKVQMWHCFDPNKDYIWAYKWNGIKAKFL
ITDKLSDNGSNLTYIWPDANNITIEECHGNNISALVNFCFLVEIMDDCIVLIEAIGASIDQDIYTTEPAT
NSYVLKYLKDQNTSLKVGNKPVIIQEYYPPPLPNSYNREKFDGMIIVQDDMIIKWKIPTIDVKCIAPFKY
KIADDVLDFDFEGIPGKIYEISYKNEILRQRNDRIVASSPQEYAIFLESAKHLQ

>AKH40361.1 putative gp93-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MDLTLEHVTSWSCHLHSKETCVMKYYNGSYYHVIPVKNISVLAQTYNSQKIPDEFWEDLGPTPYMTAIYY
SDCVANVDMFRIILELFRNLDDSFLKFSTSNTPSDFIKRHIITDGIKRITLCNKHLLKSCKTKSNRPQTF
YTKDQWIKAILKGLFPKIDSSDKSGIPTNTPDWAIKLYPRGATSISAVTTPSSQMTHLAN

>AKH40367.1 putative gp19-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MGVIRMTWNILSILITVIFVIALIWFVLYPTPIKYVLQCFVPKTEYEPNANYTTVKNYILYTNAKSNHTK
LIVIIPGGAGLLNSIANIYGFMNKLNETLGDDYDILTFSYPVRFKHTIRDSMLRVNEVLSDFTHYEEIHG
IGLSFGSLLLGAFNNKESNILSSQQMQVPQIGIKFKTFTGICGMYQPFFNVKLLTWLFDFYIMRGTPGIK
LYSCYGMPIPKLIITSNSDFLVSQSTKFLQSENAESLSYPTANLPHTFPQYINLPEAQQSIVKIVDFIKQ
NSN

>AKH40369.1 putative gp83-like protein [Kallithea virus]
MSESKLQHLHPEIINYYKSIKANGLKSPKMENNEEFITTLDRVEDDFKIPFISTYVLINNAYRHELSSNR
AKSIKQNIHAIREAKDVKIRTEVTAKVNKFEFIPSHFYTCSSKAIKVAVALFLRPAYTETLKRDFIFSLL
NHHSKTHTVSDVIDLCQKTIGDVRAFIKTVGNLNTTEKQRKQLICGLIECSELLRDRLCSKLAISVSLNG
YISLISLYLKHGHLKNVIPFEPLINLYVKESIAKCTQEEERVKILNQFKVDPVATIDDVIKGLPPAPNKV
SNSSTKSCVFKPDQNYQYYKGAPNYTRDIITTYHIEHGRRYRIQTYNDCLYDVLGYTLEAPNFLEATHSP
TTNGISAIEHEIYDRMSWSDRLNLIRFRTKIRIEDAKGSELNDYHGNSTDITISWFDDNEISCSKTISLK
KSDNKK
```

Comment: Are these very long lines or the record spans multiple lines? Ok, do it like so: 1) Replace empty line by a unqiue character, like `~`. Ot's simple ex. in `sed`. 2) Then read it in awk, set record separator to that character from point 1, ex. `~` and field separator to space. 3) then inside awk remove duplicates on the first field, there is a stackoverflow answer how to do it. 4) replace `~` back to newline. Alternatively: If the whole records are equal, just replace empty line with zero byte and `sort -z | uniq -z`

Comment: If  the answers you received for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58921665/remove-duplicated-sequence-into-fasta-file-huge-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58862586/remove-duplicated-fasta-sequence-bash-of-biopython-method didn't solve your problem, you should post comments about why they are not working and not continue reposting the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you need. Please let me know if it works for you :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";}
{ 
    split($1,descs," "); 
    for(i=2; i <= length(descs); i++){ 
        second_names[NR] = second_names[NR] " " descs[i] 
    }
    already_seen = 0
    for(c=1; c <= length(seen_names); c++ ) {
        if (second_names[NR] == seen_names[c]) {
            already_seen = 1
        }
    }
    if(already_seen == 0) {
        print $0
        print "\n"
        seen_names[length(seen_names) + 1] = second_names[NR];
    }
}
' input.txt
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Simple method:
If you don't care about ordering you can simply place all of them in a dictionary where id (second name) is key. That way you are unable to have duplicates but output will not be ordered and in every duplicate only the last entry will be kept. This is as simple as parsing each unit into 3 parts and adding them into a variable.

More complex method:
Create an empty list and go over each unit one by one and check if you need to add it to list or not. This preserves ordered input and allows you to decide which duplicate you will keep.